# Are arrays implicitly created in PHP when one of its keys are assigned something?

Tags: php, variable-assignment, associative-array

Just wishing to quickly verify this.  It is different from my immediate experience from other languages whereby an array must first be declared before it can be filled with values.

Comment: I'd like to say it's good practice to declare it first, whether the language requires it or not. Another developer looking through your code feels much more comfortable seeing `$niceVariableName = Array();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, PHP will automatically create an array given any of the following

```
$foo[] = $bar;
$foo[1] = $bar;
$foo['bar'] = $bar;

// and of course
$foo = array();

// and soon to pass
$foo = [1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: This also works multidimensionally. `$foo[][] = $bar` will create $foo and $foo[0] as arrays.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "soon to pass"?

Comment: @Luke the shorthand array syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4, 1st March 2012 (7 months after this answer was written)

Answer (score 1):

PHP will create the array even without being implicitly declared, yes.

```
$array[] = ...
```

$array would be a valid array.

Answer (score 1):

$array['one'] = "one".  Is this what your asking?  Because yes, this will create a new array