# Why do I need array() in PHP, if PHP is a dynamic/weakly typed language?

Tags: php, arrays

I've seen lots of PHP code that has values and arrays passed here and there, and sometimes, right in the middle, I see `$someVar = array();`.  When do you use `array()` in PHP, if you can already pass around arrays, which I thought was supposed to be one of PHP's advantages.

Take the PHP Manual, example 1:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

```
<?php
function takes_array($input)
{
    echo "$input[0] + $input[1] = ", $input[0]+$input[1];
}
?>
```

Then from elsewhere on [another site](http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2007/04/27/fat-models-skinny-controllers/):

```
/**
 * Model for accessing schedule table
 *
 * @author Chris Hartjes
 */

class Schedule extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Schedule';
    var $useTable = 'sched2007';
    var $useDbConfig = 'stats';

    function get($week) {
        $scheduledGames = array();
        $team = array("a01" => "BUF", "a02" => "COU", "a03" => "HAG", "a04" => "TRI",
                    "a05" => "BOW", "a06" => "MCM", "a07" => "PHI", "a08" => "WMS",
                    "a09" => "LAW", "a10" => "PAD", "a11" => "POR", "a12" => "STL",
                    "n01" => "CSP", "n02" => "COL", "n03" => "MIN", "n04" => "SDQ",
                    "n05" => "BUZ", "n06" => "CAJ", "n07" => "DTR", "n08" => "SCS",
                    "n09" => "CRE", "n10" => "MAD", "n11" => "SEA", "n12" => "SPO");
        $results = $this->findAll("home LIKE 'a%' AND week = " . (int)$week);
        $data = array();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $home = $team[$result['Schedule']['home']];
            $away = $team[$result['Schedule']['away']];
            $data[$home] = array('home' => $home, 'away' => $away);
        }

        asort($data);

        foreach ($data as $home => $matchup) {
            $scheduledGames[$home] = $matchup;
        }

        $results = $this->findAll("home LIKE 'n%' AND week = " . (int)$week);
        $data = array();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $home = $team[$result['Schedule']['home']];
            $away = $team[$result['Schedule']['away']];
            $data[$home] = array('home' => $home, 'away' => $away);
        }

        asort($data);

        foreach ($data as $home => $matchup) {
            $scheduledGames[$home] = $matchup;
        }

        return $scheduledGames;
    }
}
```

Here in `$scheduledGames` you have array(), then `$team` just has the array dynamically it appear, then `$data` has array() again.

At the risk of being dumber, however, as pointed out in a comment, I believe I am confusing this with implicit arrays, so [Are arrays implicitly created in PHP when one of its keys are assigned something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853067/are-arrays-implicitly-created-in-php-when-one-of-its-keys-are-assigned-something)

Comment: You use `array()` in PHP when you need to create an array.... you can't pass arrays round if you can't create them in the first place

Comment: $team above was not declared as Array(), or at least that I can find.

Comment: This is a very specific question.  Don't know why it'd get downvoted.

Comment: `$team = array("a01" => "BUF.....);` Which part of not defining $team as an array are you missing? See [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

Comment: Can you create an array with `$foo[] = "bar";`? Yes. Should you? No! Simple

Comment: @MarkBaker What about implcit arrays?

Comment: @johnny - what about implicit arrays? Certain functions will return an array datatype such as explode().... is that what you mean by implicit?

Comment: @MarkBaker I suppose.  I think I have my answer from everyone.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can pass arrays around, that means you need some way to *create* arrays, right? That's what `array()` is, it's the language construct to create an array.

This kind of code is simply best practice:

```
$foo = array();

foreach ($bar as $baz) {
    $foo[] = $baz;
}

return $foo;
```

What if `$bar` is empty? Then the loop will not run. If you didn't initialise `$foo` as an array before the loop, then it would not exist after the loop. In that case `return $foo` would throw an error, because you're trying to return something that doesn't exist. Therefore, you always initialise your variables you're going to work on. That's what you do in virtually all languages.

Comment: I understand that.  I thought you could simply create them without explicitly using Array(), is my point.

Comment: I'd add that, even though PHP is weakly typed, simple variables (ints, floats, strings) are fundamentally different from arrays, which in turn are also fundamentally different to objects. They all still need a way to create them, even though the simple types are not declared differently.

Comment: @johnny For example how?

Comment: @deceze a misconception on my part.

Comment: @johnny OK. Just to reiterate: yes, it *is* possible to implicitly create arrays, for example with `$foo['bar'] = 'baz'`. However, again, in the example above you're simply initialising the variable itself to avoid potential errors. That it's initialised as an array because it's supposed to be an array is kind of beside the point.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is a really dynamic language, at times (according to some criticism) even too much. For example, as you probably know, you can use variables even if they are not initialized, getting only a "notice" error (despite the potential security issue).

Calls like: `$foo = array();` are used exactly for the purpose of initializing a variable with an empty array. If you want to execute array-based functions on `$foo` (for example, `array_push()`), initializing it as empty array is the best way to ensure the parser will get an array, and not a previously initialized variable (which may or may not be an array).

Eventually, note that the `$foo[n]` constructor in PHP does work also with strings, allowing access to the n-th character of the string. Initializing `$foo` as an empty array also ensures there wasn't a string before (which could potentially lead to security issues).

PS: note that from PHP 5.4 there is also a new "short syntax" to create and initialize arrays, for example `$foo = [];` is equivalent to `$foo = array();`. See http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

**Addendum**

As a clarification, also reading at your comments to other answers, it is possible to create arrays without initializing them first. For example `$foo['bar'] = 'hello world';` (with `$foo` not being initialized before) would work. *However*, that is extremely unsafe: you cannot know what `$foo` was before, and it could have been already initialized/used previously in the scope (even by other developers if you work on the same code! - never make assumptions). In this case, see the following code:

```
<?php
// Previously somewhere in the code
$foo = 'hello world';

// … some other code

// Trying to create an array
$foo[0] = 'A';

var_dump($foo);
// Expected (if $foo was unset): array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" }
// Actual: string(11) "Aello world"
```

Needless to say, this is a potential security threat.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `$scheduledGames = array();` in your example is to initialise a variable to an empty array, not to define its type. This is an important distinction, since `$scheduleGames` could easily be set to a string, integer or object later on in the code; it is not bound to the type of array.

In the example, without initialising `$scheduledGames` in this way, the `return $scheduledGames;` line has issues, since it is possible for this line to be called without having any result from the findAll statements, which would result in error.